# Kibana select all true values by another term

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have index with 2 fields:

1. Error: boolean
2. Region: string

I'd like to visualize count of all error:true values group by region in grid using Kibana 4.4.2

I can't found such method in UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "Filter" aggregation. For example: Data table visualization -> Split rows -> Aggregation: Filter -> Filter: error:true.   After that you can add sub aggregation "Term" by Region